# How to delete a marker

Tags: marker

**Q**:  How can I delete a marker after it has been created?

I see how to create markers and how to move markers, but I see nothing in the manual about how to delete them:

- Creating:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Markers.html#Creating-Markers
- Moving:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Moving-Markers.html#Moving-Markers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Markers that point nowhere are garbage-collected.  From the Elisp manual, node [Overview of Markers](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overview-of-Markers.html):

> Insertion and deletion in a buffer must check all the markers and
>   relocate them if necessary.  This slows processing in a buffer with a
>   large number of markers.  For this reason, it is a good idea to make a
>   marker point nowhere if you are sure you don’t need it any more.
>   Markers that can no longer be accessed are eventually removed (*note
>   Garbage Collection::).

To make a marker point nowhere, use `set-marker` to set it to `nil`:

```
(set-marker my-marker nil)
```

Is that not enough for you? Can you explain why you want to explicitly (i.e., immediately) delete a marker?

Comment: Not original questioner but creating markers in a function calls into unknown code which could raise an error, I need to know if I should use `unwind-protect` and set-marker to nil in case of failure.

Comment: Sorry; I don't understand what you're looking for / asking. The question, not comments, is the place to clarify it. You might want to pose a separate question, showing some code or specifying the context more clearly etc.

Comment: I had the same question as the questioner, the "why" may be the same - they don't state why.

I just mention if markers are created in code that might later error... this seems like a case where the script author may want to clean up - although that can be a question on it's own since I'm not sure of what's the best practice in this case.

Comment: Asked a related question https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/69117